# Connect local database c#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I want to create a empty local database inside my project's folder and I've error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

on the line

```
conn.Open();
```

I'm lost with what I need to do. Any idea what is causing this? I tried a few solutions - this one of them...

```
SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = bd-avalia.sdf; Password ='<asdasd>'");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "create table cliente(id_cliente int identity not null primary key, nome varchar not null, password not null int)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

the error:
 [image]

Comment: Try the password without the angled brackets or quotes and see if you fare any better

Comment: when creating the table you also set password to be an int...I'm assuming you would want it to be a varchar

Comment: Does the file `bd-avalia.sdf` really exist **in the current run directory**? If you're running this inside Visual Studio, the app is run inside the `(project-directory)\bin\debug` folder - is that `.sdf` file available there? Try using a **full, complete path** - does that work?

Comment: Why dont you declare the conection in the web.config then just call it in your sql connection?

Comment: Is the file bd-avalia.sdf a part of your project? The connection string to data in your project is `"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bd-avalia.sdf; ..."`.

Comment: the file bd-avalia.sdf exist in project's folder and the file is a part of my project!

Comment: I declare the conection in the app.config

Answer (score 1):

If you debug into the code (or output it somehow) you can check the `NativeError` property of the `SqlCeException`, which should tell you the cause of the exception.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237948(v=sql.80).aspx for the explanation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `cmd.CommandText` as follows:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = bd-avalia.sdf; Password ='<asdasd>'");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE dbo.[cliente] ([id_cliente] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                       nome [varchar] NOT NULL, password [int] NOT NULL)";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Change the cmd.CommandText as follows:

"CREATE TABLE dbo.[cliente] ([id_cliente] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, nome [varchar] NOT NULL, password [int] NOT NULL)";